# how to understand space complexity correctly?

Tags: space-complexity

I am very confused for space complexity.
If I use HashMap or ArrayList or other data structure, dose this mean I have made a new space,so the space complexity is linear?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, about your question: `If I use HashMap or ArrayList or other data structure, dose this mean I have made a new space,so the space complexity is linear?`

The answer is "No, the space complexity is not linear."
These data structures have their implementations. So the space complexity depends on the structure's implementation.
For example(in Java):

ArrayList: It's implemented by Resizable-array. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. So If you use it, the space complexity will add the actual size of this ArrayList in you program.

HashMap: It's a bit more complex.
The elements in HashMap are stored in
`transient Entry[] table;`
And the implementation of Entry is:

`static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {

        final K key;

        V value;

        Entry<K,V> next;

        final int hash;

 .........

}`
[Here are more details.](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-internal)

As we know, there are two main characteristics for programs:
1. Time complexity  --> CPU usage
2. Space complexity  --> RAM usage

The space complexity of a program (for a given input) is the number of elementary objects that this program needs to store during its execution.
This number is computed with respect to the size n of the input data.

Space complexity: example 1
`// note: x is an unsorted array
int findMin(int[] x) {
    int k = 0; int n = x.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (x[i] < x[k]) {
        k = i;
        }
    }
    return k;
}`
S(ﬁndMin, n) = n + 2
T(ﬁndMin, n) = O(n)

Space complexity: example 2
`// note: x is an unsorted array
void multVect(int[] x, int[][] a) {
    int k = 0; int n = x.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        a[i][j] = x[i] * x[j]
        }
    }
}`
S(multVect, n) = n × n + 2
T(multVect, n) = O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

Space complexity means the space the algorithm needs to run.

**Example 1: Sorting-Algorithms**
All sorting algorithms need at least `O(n)` space to save the list (of length `n`) they have to sort

1. Bubblesort (and most other sorting algorithms too) can work *in-place*, this means that it needs no more space as it needs to save the list. (just searching two elements in the wrong order and swaping them)
2. *Stupid-Sort* lists all permutations of the input list (and saves them) and then searching the sorted one. Since there are `n!` permutations this algorithm needs `O(n * n!)` space.

**Example 2: Number representation**
A number `n` can be saved in different ways:

1. binary (or any other base `≥2`): this needs `O(log n)` space, due to `n = 2log n`
2. unary: here you write `n` as a sum of ones (`n = 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + ... +  1`) and you have to save every one. So this needs `O(n)` space, due to `n = n ⋅ 1`.

Sorry for this silly, useless examples. I just choose something simple.